# JQUERY loop though elements; looping forever

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I am trying to sort an exercise and I can't make it work. I am trying to make a slide of a navigation (see JSFIDDLE: **https://jsfiddle.net/ka8wmxy0/** ); and it does the job, but I want to say "when it arrives to the last element, move to the start", as at the moment, you can press the arrow and it will keep moving to the left forever.

I was trying to loop through the total of elements of the list, but I don't know how to build the function properly. Can anyone give me a hand?

Thank you

html:

```
 <div class="DocumentList">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="DocumentItem">
              <a href="">
                <p>Manufracturer</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="DocumentItem">
              <a href="">
                <p>Customer 1st</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="DocumentItem">
              <a href="">
                <p>Excess</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="DocumentItem">
              <a href="">
                <p>Friendly Form</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="DocumentItem">
              <a href="">
                <p>FREE</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <span id="arrow">ARROW</span>
        </div>
```

css:

```
.list-inline li {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid pink;
}
.DocumentList {
  overflow-x:visible;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.list-inline {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#arrow {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  padding:2%;
}
```

js:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  checkSize();
});

function checkSize() {
    var totalElements = ($(".DocumentItem").length)+1;
$('#arrow').click(function() {
   $(".list-inline").animate({'margin-left': '+=-50px'});
 });
    }


$(document).ready(function() {
       checkSize();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the `$("#arrow").click(function(){...})` out of the `checkSize()` function.

Further, you can add an `if` condition inside the `.click()` function.

Like this

```
if ($(".DocumentItem").last().offset().left <= 0) {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
      'margin-left': 0
    });
} else {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
      'margin-left': '+=-50px'
    });
}
```

If you wish to reset the list without that "extra" click, replace the condition inside the `if` statement to following

```
if($(".DocumentItem").last().offset().left - 50 <= 0){...}else{...}
```

**Take a look at the snippet**

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  checkSize();
});

function checkSize() {
  var totalElements = ($(".DocumentItem").length) + 1;

}

$('#arrow').click(function() {
  if ($(".DocumentItem").last().offset().left <= 0) {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
      'margin-left': 0
    });
  } else {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
      'margin-left': '+=-50px'
    });
  }

});


$(document).ready(function() {
  checkSize();
});
```

```css
.list-inline li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
.DocumentList {
  overflow-x: visible;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.list-inline {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#arrow {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DocumentList">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="DocumentItem">
      <a href="">
        <p>Manufracturer</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
      <a href="">
        <p>Customer 1st</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
      <a href="">
        <p>Excess</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
      <a href="">
        <p>Friendly Form</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
      <a href="">
        <p>FREE</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span id="arrow">ARROW</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but.... why do I need to put the click outside the function? the thing is, inside that function I do an if statement for width less than 623px, so I think I have to put it inside the function, isn't it? :S

Comment: the `click()` function is being bound to an `event` (the `click` event obviously). It triggers whenever you click, no matter what screen size. *" Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element."* [jQuery Docs .click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)